# Pandas / PEP8 - Is it correct to have such a long line of code? Can it be improved?

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, pep8

When working through code I usually build long lines like this, but already I've forgotten what’s going on, and I find having it like this is hard to read. I would have to deconstruct and run each section to see what is really going on.

BUT when teaching myself the resources I learnt from said advanced users would use one line of code when beginners would use many.

So my question really is:

Would it be better to have this one line (kept as it is)? And if so how can it be formatted to be under 79 characters (as per PEP8)?

Or is it better to break this down into chunks so it’s easier to come back to at a later date (or is it strange I can't understand it like this)?

```
top_products_for_customer_group = stock_trans[(stock_trans["SA_DACCNT"].isin(customer_seg_df[self.customer_seg_df["Label"] == customer_seg_df[self.customer_seg_df["SA_DACCNT"] == acc]["Label"].iloc[0]]["SA_DACCNT"]))].groupby(["SA_PRODUCT", "SA_DESC"]).count()["SA_ACCOUNT"].reset_index().sort_values("SA_ACCOUNT", ascending=False)
```

Comment: "*advanced users would use one line of code when beginners would use many*" I don't think this is true. It may be the case that for doing the same thing an advanced user needs a line of code but a beginner needs several lines of code but that doesn't mean squashing multiple lines into a single one. This is more of a personal style but I would say name whatever can be named naturally. For example save whatever collection you are referring to in `ser.isin(collection))` to a variable.

Comment: It is considered bad style, at least by people concerned about writing readable, maintainable code. Ideally, your code is self-documenting

Comment: I agree with @ayhan and I'd like to add, don't be (too) shy with adding a function. I don't know the context, but I have a feeling that a lot of that code is re-used somewhere else, just for the sake of having one-liners, while it could be encapsulated in a function of which the name could be self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking the lines makes the code easier to read, but still requires re-engineering every time a problem occurs or changes have to be made. This is highly unprofessional code.

```
top_products_for_customer_group = (
    stock_trans[(
        stock_trans["SA_DACCNT"].isin(
            customer_seg_df[
                self.customer_seg_df["Label"] == customer_seg_df[
                    self.customer_seg_df["SA_DACCNT"] == acc
                ]["Label"].iloc[0]
            ]["SA_DACCNT"]
        )
    )]
    .groupby(["SA_PRODUCT", "SA_DESC"])
    .count()["SA_ACCOUNT"]
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values("SA_ACCOUNT", ascending=False)
)
```